# Issue with Plotly Figure Factory rug_text

Tags: python, plotly

I'm looking to create a distplot using plotly's figure factory and would like to set custom rug text. I've formatted the text exactly as is shown in plotly's documentation, but haven't been able to get that to show up.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

group_labels = ([sample_df[c] for c in sample_df.columns],)
colors = ["#333F44", "#37AA9C"]

fig = ff.create_distplot(
    [sample_df[c] for c in sample_df.columns],
    sample_df.columns,
    show_hist=False,
    rug_text=rug_text,
)

# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text="DistPlot")
fig.show()
```

Please find a sample df below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'machine learning engineer':[68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 22.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 97.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 54.0,
 69.0,
 69.0,
 69.0,
 69.0,
 69.0,
 69.0,
 69.0,
 69.0],
'python developer': [68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 68.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 71.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 33.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 79.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 94.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 77.0,
 41.0,
 41.0,
 41.0,
 41.0,
 41.0,
 41.0,
 65.0,
 65.0,
 65.0,
 65.0,
 65.0,
 65.0,
 8.0,
 8.0,
 8.0,
 8.0,
 8.0,
 35.0,
 35.0,
 35.0,
 35.0,
 35.0,
 57.0]})
```

I would like the rug hover text to display the following rug_text:

```
[['Machine Learning',
  'Scikit-learn',
  'Python',
  'Flask',
  'Linux',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'Data Science'],
 ['React',
  'Django',
  'Amazon Web Services (AWS)',
  'JavaScript',
  'MongoDB',
  'jQuery',
  'Python',
  'Linux',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'MySQL',
  'Git']]
```

Has anyone had issues with setting custom rug text with plotly's figure factory distplot? Thanks so much! Please find a link to plotly's documentation below: https://plotly.com/python/distplot/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the hover text not showing up is that the number of data does not match the number of text, so it does not show up. In the sample on this official API page, the number of data and the number of hover text are the same. I have run it and checked. See [here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_distplot.html). I will post an example of running it with your hover text count matching the data count.

```
rug_text = [['Machine Learning',
  'Scikit-learn',
  'Python',
  'Flask',
  'Linux',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'Data Science']*13,
 ['React',
  'Django',
  'Amazon Web Services (AWS)',
  'JavaScript',
  'MongoDB',
  'jQuery',
  'Python',
  'Linux',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'MySQL',
  'Git']*9]
```

[image]